# Read Second audio track stream from mp4 file using SharpDx or IMSourceReader

Tags: c#, audio, sharpdx, ms-media-foundation

I have a requirement in my application where I have to read all the available track stream from mp4 file.

Mp4 file is encoded with number of tracks in AAC format. I have to decode to get all available tracks from the file. Currently I am using SharpDX and IMSourceReader (Media Foundation dlls) to read the Streams. But by default SourceReader returns only the first audio stream from the file. Is it I am doing correct ? Or I have to use any other third party libraries to achieve this ?

Comment: FYI tried to open an MP4 with multiple audio tracks with SDK topoedit app, and I see the that Media Foundation is definitely capable of reading multiple audio tracks.

Comment: If yes. Can you share the code that will be used to read the number of audio tracks.

Comment: I don't have code - [Topoedit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows it possible, so you can look into SharpDX why it is not picked up (SharpDX just picks first audio track and skips the rest?).

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the [reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can select which streams will be delivered when reading samples.  Often times you do not wish to select the stream.  An example would be a movie which has additional audio streams (spanish, french, or perhaps director commentary).  As a result, most of the time stream selection is as simple as the following:

```
// error checking omitted for brevity
hr = reader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, nullptr, audioMediaType);
hr = reader->SetStreamSelection((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, true);
```

However if you look at [SetStreamSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374669(v=vs.85).aspx), the first parameter takes either the enumeration used above, or a specific stream index.

```
// 0–0xFFFFFFFB  <-- The zero-based index of a stream.
//   0xFFFFFFFC  <-- MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM
//   0xFFFFFFFD  <-- MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM
//   0xFFFFFFFE  <-- MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS
//   0xFFFFFFFE  <-- MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM
//   0xFFFFFFFF  <-- MF_SOURCE_READER_INVALID_STREAM_INDEX
```

I have never used SharpDX, but this enumeration is documented [here](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-mediafoundation-sourcereaderindex).
Pertaining to video, sometimes additional video streams are available (usually closed captioning).

When reading the samples, using a [callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374658(v=vs.85).aspx) or [synchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374665(v=vs.85).aspx), pay close attention to the stream index, and process the sample accordingly.

You may also find these answers valuable or interesting:
  [Aggregate Media Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917256/windows-media-foundation-recording-audio/22819850#22819850)
  [MP4 IMFSinkWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129263/cant-add-audio-stream-to-mp4-file-using-sinkwriter-from-media-foundation/29375021#29375021)
  [Adding Audio Sample to Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352989/audio-sample-adding-to-a-video-using-sink-writer-in-windows-media-foundation/27388162#27388162)
  [Creating NV12 Encoded Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038569/creating-nv12-encoded-video-using-windows-media-foundation/26068214#26068214)
  [IMFSinkWriter Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935480/bug-in-imfsinkwriter/30328401#30328401)
  [IMFSinkWriter CPU Utilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322263/mft-encoder-h264-high-cpu-utilization/30329660#30329660)

I hope this helps.